# Resetting an environment to shiny inputs

Tags: r, shiny

I'm not new to Shiny, but I struggle with it.

I designed a package that uses a global environment (`PARAMETERS`) to store parameters. After moving this into a shiny app, inputs from the shiny app update `PARAMETERS`.

However I often change `PARAMETERS` manually, to produce an appropriate graph for the output.

What I'm struggling with is when I go to make another output, how do I restore `PARAMETERS` to the values in the shiny inputs.

It would be nice to have a function which I can use in multiple places that re-reads all the inputs, and resets `PARAMETERS` to those values.

If I use `reactive` it won't work, because the inputs haven't changed, so it isn't going prompt a change.

I'm not sure I can provide a reproducible example, but in pseudocode what I'm thinking is:

```
# Store all the input values inside a reactiveValue
parameters <- reactive({
  list(
    A = input$A,
    B = input$B
  )
})
# And then have another function that reads from the reactive object into the `PARAMETERS` environment
reset_parameters <- reactive({
  PARAMETERS$A = parameters()$A
  PARAMETERS$B = parameters()$B
})
```

But this doesn't work, because I update `PARAMETERS` not `parameters()` or `input`, so it's not re-evaluated.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `reactiveValues` instead, where you can modify a single item inside a reactive context.

Here is an example:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("a", "a"),
  actionButton("b", "b"),
  actionButton("c", "c")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  param <- reactiveValues(a = 123, b = 456) # set default
  # change param based on inputs
  observeEvent(input$a,{
      param$a <- input$a
      print(reactiveValuesToList(param))
  })  
  observeEvent(input$b,{
      param$b <- input$b
      print(reactiveValuesToList(param))
  })
  # manually change param to a number
  observeEvent(input$c,{
      param$a <- 111
      param$b <- 222
      print(reactiveValuesToList(param))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Look closely at how the values in `param` change when you click the buttons.

Read more here: https://mastering-shiny.org/reactivity-objects.html